# Interpreting paths in SVG files

Tags: image, svg

I've generated a plain svg file using Inkscape containing three paths. Consider one of the paths inside the .svg file given below

```
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       d="m 128.57143,243.79075 
          -2.85714,568.57143 
           474.28571,0 
          -31.42857,-611.42857 z" id="path2985"
style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"/>
```

I want to parse this svg file to extract the XY coordinates of this closed path (it is closed because of the 'z' at the end of the coordinates list).

I am unsure how to interpret the 8 numbers. From what I understand, the first two numbers indicated by `m 128.57143,243.79075` means that the path's origin is in screen-coordinates (not Cartesian!) at 128.57143 right and 243.79075 down from the top-left of the screen.

What about the rest of the 6 numbers? Do they indicate vectors in which to move relative to the previous point? Or just absolute screen coordinates?

As indicated in the SVG documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp), SVG files usually have those M,L,H,...letters prefixed to each successive number pair which tells the vector-graphics viewer how to interpret that number pair while drawing that path.

In this case however, other than the `m` prefixed at the beginnnig and the `z` at the end there are no such letters in between. What then is the default behaviour in this case?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A capital letter M would suggest absolute coördinates. And a small m means relative coördinates. Since positioning is 0,0 by default, the first value of m would be identical to M.

Only the first coördinates are treated as 'm' (=moveto). The next ones are treated as 'l' (=lineto). Since 'm' was not capitalised the next coördinate will be treated as relative.

It would be the same as:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       d="m 128.57143,243.79075 
          l-2.85714,568.57143 
           474.28571,0 
          -31.42857,-611.42857 z" id="path2985"
style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"/>
```

For the sake of reference: this is what the spec sais about the moveto command. (source: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands)

> Start a new sub-path at the given (x,y) coordinate. M (uppercase)
>   indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; m (lowercase)
>   indicates that relative coordinates will follow. If a moveto is
>   followed by multiple pairs of coordinates, the subsequent pairs are
>   treated as implicit lineto commands. Hence, implicit lineto commands
>   will be relative if the moveto is relative, and absolute if the moveto
>   is absolute. If a relative moveto (m) appears as the first element of
>   the path, then it is treated as a pair of absolute coordinates. In
>   this case, subsequent pairs of coordinates are treated as relative
>   even though the initial moveto is interpreted as an absolute moveto.